# java using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: java

I am having trouble clearing the following error '(' or '[' expected on the second line of case 2 and case 3.  The code I have written is newAnimal.displayInfo();

I am not sure why I get this error on case 2 and 3 but not case 1.  Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any assistance/guidance will be appreciated.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
package animalinfo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnimalInfo 
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Animal newAnimal;
    int quit = 4;
    while(-4 != quit);
    {
        System.out.println("\n1) Camel" +
                "\n2)Penguin" +
                "\n3) Tortoise" +
                "\n4) Exit Program.");
        System.out.print("Please select an amimalfrom the list.");

        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice)    
    {    
        case 1: 
            newAnimal = new Camel();
            newAnimal.displayInfo();
            break;
        case 2:
            newAnimal = new Penguin
            newAnimal.displayInfo();
            break;
        case 3:
            newAnimal = new Tortoise
            newAnimal.displayInfo();
            break;     

        case 4:
            System.out.println ("Thank you for making your selections.");
            break;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(-4 != quit);
```

Get rid of the semicolon, should just be

```
while (-4 != quit) 
{ 
    /*Code here*/ 
}
```

and yes, when you have `new Penguin` and `new Tortoise`, you are missing the parentheses and semicolon

Comment: Thank you!  it seems sometimes it is the small stuff that trips me up.  As a beginner I am realizing how very important the details are.  Thanks again!  your feedback was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're missing parentheses after creating the new objects. So this:

```
newAnimal = new Penguin
```

should become this:

```
newAnimal = new Penguin();
```

This is because you're setting newAnimal to a new instance of a Penguin object, and to create that new instance you must call the [constructor](http://www.javatpoint.com/constructor) of the Penguin class to create the object.

Also, as [Jurko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30292696/1229855) stated, your while loop is set up incorrectly.

```
while(-4 != quit);
```

You must remove the semicolon, otherwise the loop will indefinitely run without executing the code you have underneath it. The correct syntax for a while loop is

```
while (-4 != quit) {
  // Code to repeat here
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I found your feedback extremely helpful.  I was looking at the code for such a long time I did not notice the items I overlooked.  Thanks again!